# PowerBI Datesbetween - Line Chart Visualisation

Tags: charts, line, powerbi

I am trying to plot on a line chart running data for 3 fiscal years. My fiscal year being 30 June and not 31 December

*Data for Year 1 [1 July 2015 to 30 June 2016]*

*Data for Year 2 [1 July 2016 to 30 June 2017]*

*Data for Year 3 [1 July 2016 to 30 June 2018]* ***This is the current year***

The following is what I am hoping to achieve.
[3 Year Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0KCa.jpg)
[image]

I am not certain how to achieve this.

I was thinking the following might be  of some relevance

```
Revenue from Start = CALCULATE(Report[Revenue], DATESBETWEEN('Dates'[Date], BLANK(), LASTDATE('Dates'[Date])))
```

I have had it suggested to set up a new measure "Date2". But I really am not sure how to do this. Also given that I am after a third series would I then need to set up a "Date3"

For Date2 [and Date3 if applicable], how would this/these measures be coded, ie is this logical

```
Date2 = DATE(2015,07,01)
Date3 = DATE(2016,07,01)
```

Thanks for any help that can be offered. You will see from my question, I know what I want as an output, but have no idea how to really implement.

Comment: Why can't you just use Revenue measure against Date?  If your requirement is more complex then you need to explain it.

Comment: Revenue is on a daily basis so over the fiscal year it accumulates from zero to the final total, it then resets at the new fiscal year to zero and then accumulates to the final total, same for year 3.

I have no issue in doing an accumulation from the beginning of the first year to the end of the third year. 

So my question is how do I create 3 sequences from one dataset. 

Please let me know if that helps with understanding my query,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the TOTALYTD function, e.g.

```
Revenue from Start = TOTALYTD ( [Revenue] , 'Dates'[Date] , "30 June 2018" )
```

This blog post is probably the best description of this and related functions:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/time-intelligence-in-power-bi-desktop/

Comment: Thanks Mike, that is what I am after. :)